# Searching MySQL like keywords should return 1 result but returns false

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to display 3 event names that are similar to this event name.

Currently build this code returns `FALSE` and I cant see why:

calling(no problem here that I can see):

```
// get 3 similar events (by name)
$nameArray      = explode(" ", strtolower($name));
var_dump($similarEvents     = $event->getSimilarEvents($event_id, $nameArray));
```

method that gets the 3 events that are similar by name

```
public function getSimilarEvents($event_id, $nameArray){

$uniqueWords = array();

// list of common words we dont want to search by
$commonWords = array('one');

// Build array of words that dont match common words
$uniqueWords = array_diff($nameArray, $commonWords);

// add each AND per word in array
foreach($uniqueWords AS $word){
    $x++;
    if($x==1){
        $like .= "event_name LIKE %$word% ";
    }else{
        $like .= " AND event_name LIKE %$word%";
    }
}

// build start of mysql query
$query = "SELECT event_id, event_name FROM adrenaline_junkies_uk_events WHERE ? AND event_id <> ? LIMIT 3";
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $like, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $event_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($query);
var_dump($like);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}else{
    return FALSE;
    }
}
```

the `var_dump` of `$query` returns:

> string(95) "SELECT event_id, event_name FROM
>   adrenaline_junkies_uk_events WHERE ? AND event_id <> ? LIMIT 3"

the `var_dump` of `$like` returns:

> string(82) "event_name LIKE %mountain% AND event_name LIKE %test% AND
>   event_name LIKE %event%"

The method is returning `FALSE` when it should return one other event that has a similar name. This definitely exists in the database.

edit:

title of first event:

> Man vs. Mountain

title of second event

> mountain test event one

As you can see it should return the other event because they share the word `mountain`.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use bound parameters like that. You can only use them for individual values.

Comment: Agree with @andrewsi your second bound parameter is done correctly. Your first is incorrect.

Comment: Hi thanks, could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: @crm - when you use a bound parameter, the database assumes that the contents is a single value. So your query is being run as `WHERE 'event_name LIKE %$word%' AND event_id....` - the database is treating that whole first parameter as a single value.